# NiFi How to query Content Repository from NiFi Flow

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I have a use case where I need to use FlowFile from another flow.

As I know all flowfiles are saved into Content Repository.

So, for example, my first flow reads data from DB, performs some transformations and puts in to Hive.

My second flow needs to get those transformed flowfiles and put them to another place or perform some filtering, etc.

How can I get those flowfiles from content repo in NiFi flow?

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken, the content of the flow files is saved into the Content Repository. 
You don't need to query the Content Repository to use those FlowFiles.. I assume that you are using `PutHiveQL`, so just use the `success` relationship for your next flow.

Example: `ExecuteSQL` ->(success) `Transform Process Group` ->(output) PutHiveQL ->(success) -> Next Flow

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if i want to use the result of "transform" in another flow after the day from executing first flow?
I don't want to re-execute first flow again...

Comment: You could either penalize those FlowFiles for a day using `ExecuteScript`, or just schedule the next flow's first processor to run once a day.

Comment: I mean that my first flow doesn't know that it's flowfiles may be used in another flow.
Flows are not connected.
So, it means,I cannot get flowfiles from content repository and use them?

Comment: It would be very difficult. Why not connect those two flows in some way? You don't have to do this directly, you can use 3rd party like Kafka for that